# question about isomorphism involving Dihedral group.

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups

suppose $D_{n}$ is dihedral group with order $2n$, do we have this Isomorphism below?
$$D_{2k+1} \times \mathbb{Z}_2 \simeq  D_{4k+2}$$

I think it is wrong, I couldn't find any mapping, but I couldn't find any counterexample, it will be great if you help me with this,thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider a $(4k+2)$-gon $A$ and a $(2k+1)$-gon $B$ otained by taking only every second vertex of $A$. Every symmetry of $B$ is also a symmetry of $A$. Additionally, reflection at the origin (or: rotation by 180 degrees) is a symmetry of $A$. As this reflection has orde $2$ and commutes with the other symmetries, we have thus obtained the desired group isomorphism.